# Swift macOS Process.run() port leak

Tags: swift, macos, memory-leaks, process, macos-mojave

Current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/swift

import Foundation

func runSleepProcess() {
    let sleepProcess = Process()
    sleepProcess.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/sleep")
    sleepProcess.arguments = ["0"]
    try? sleepProcess.run()
    sleepProcess.waitUntilExit()
}

while true {
    runSleepProcess()
}
```

Looking in activity monitor, it seems that the mach port usage increases by 1 each loop.  Is this expected behavior when running an external process?  If not, how do I fix the leak?  Thanks.

Comment: I ran your script on macOS High Sierra (10.13.6) and the number of *match ports* used *maxed out* around 40. How high your number goes?

Comment: @PauloMattos sorry, I should have mentioned in the original post: I'm on macOS 10.14.3, and Activity Monitor shows over 1,000 ports in less than a minute.

Comment: @apple9321 I have looked at your problem and updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not expected behaviour and this problem is already reported. The workaround for this is using `posix_spawn` instead of `Process`.